# Deleting all Webform Submissions and Content from specific IP

Tags: webforms

Is there a great way to delete all content and webform submissions from a specific IP address? I'm sure it can be done with MySQL commands, but I'm hoping there's a 'safer' way to do it than manipulating the database by hand.

Thanks!

Drupal 7.50 Commons

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Views Bulk Operations](http://Views%20Bulk%20Operations%20(VBO)).

Add `Bulk operations: Content` as a field and check mark `Delete item` under Selected Bulk Operations. Make your view format as Table.

You could try using [IP Address manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip) or [User IP Log](https://www.drupal.org/project/uiplog) and hopefully one of these modules will allow you to add IP address as a field to your view.

In your View, under Advanced, you may possibly need to add a relationship of author to your view so you can access user fields (IP Field).